# Exchange Server 2003 and Iphone activesync issues

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, iphone

I have been trying to find a solution for this problem everywhere.  I am trying to sync my iphone to my work email, I can perform the setup on the iphone and it works fine but when I try to connect it says connection to server has failed.  I've read something about the mailbox not creating the Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync folder so it won't sync.  Here is the message the server eventlog gives

Unexpected Exchange mailbox Server error: Server: [TECNOSEDIA-DC1.tecnosedia.local] User: [Henderson@tscustomfurniture.com] HTTP status code: [409]. Verify that the Exchange mailbox Server is working correctly.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What version of iOS is your phone running.  The newer the better for ActiveSync support.

Comment: Have you setup any other mobile devices with your Exchange server? This will let us know if OWA is setup correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Does the user have the "Allow Mobile Access" bit set?  (Must use the exchange ADU&C tool to set it... as the regular ADU&C is missing all of the exchange features)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working after deleting and reinstalling all exchange related Virtual Directories and running adsutil from the command prompt, then restarting Microsoft Exchange System Attendant.  I can sync any mobile device with teh exchange server now.

Thanks,